# Reduction in profit...by how much

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

> If an organization sells $n$ tickets then the profit would be 20% more than the total costs of production. Lets say that it  sold all the tickets except 5% of them. What is the reduction in profit?

How to tackle these problems?

#### Progress

I have got the answer, selling price would be $1.2 and if 95 tickets sold then selling price be 114 that means 14% profit. Answer posted below.

Comment: You could try a specific case. Say the production cost was $1.00 per ticket and there were 100 tickets produced.  What would happen?  Use the specific example to then guide your general thinking.  On one like this it is not immediately clear (at least to me) that the answer is the same in all possible scenarios.

Comment: great thanks Mr.Paw88789 I have got the answer, selling price would be $\$$1.2 and if 95 tickets sold then selling price be 114 that means 14% profit....:-)

Comment: @900 sit-ups a day Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$n$ be $100$ tickets and each be $\$$$1.00$ then

total cost = $100$x$\$$$1.00$ = $\$$$100$

total Selling price is, 120% greater than cost = $120$$\$$

each ticket be $\frac{120}{100}$ = $\$$$1.2$

if 95% of 100 tickets are sold then 95 tickets are sold

Selling price be $95$x$1.2$ = $\$$$114$

hence profit is $14$%..